# Java how to import package project into my project with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have in the same folder two others folders :

- aaa-ui
- bbb-features

I'm using IntelliJ how can I add the package (by import) into my ui project ?

Comment: Make one module to depend on another, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency.

Comment: Are the folders different projects, modules or just different packages? In the last case, just use `import bbb-features.TheClassYouNeed`.